# Proper use of quotes (php echo html)

Tags: php, html

I am a bit lost in using quotes. I know that if I use `"` at parent then I can use `'` in child but how can I fix something like this?:

```
echo '<a href=site.php?id="$row['id']">Found $count rows in evidence data.</a> <br>';
```

This throw error :

```
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' inlass\data2.php on line 87`
```

It just  always display $row (php code) as random text so link looks likesite.php?id=rowid  or it just do not do anything and throw error with ' ". Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Syntax issue, Try this code,

```
echo '<a href="site.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Found '.$count.' rows in evidence data.</a> <br>';
```

OR

```
echo "<a href=\"site.php?id={$row['id']}\">Found {$count} rows in evidence data.</a> <br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use \ to escape the special characters

```
echo '<a href=site.php?id="$row[\'id\']">Found $count rows in evidence data.</a> <br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with

```
echo '<a href=site.php?id="'.$row['id'].'">Found '.$count.' rows in evidence data.</a> <br>';
```

Comment: Hey mate , your code work , thanks. But may i ask why it say " Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' i " ?

Comment: Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type. Check Here http://docs.php.net/manual/da/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<a href='site.php?id=".$row['id'].">Found ".$count." rows in evidence data.</a><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using variables inside the quote than you should close the quotes and than you should join the variable with it. Try the code below

```
echo '<a href=site.php?id="'.$row['id'].'">Found '.$count.' rows in evidence data.</a> <br>';
```

Or You can use this code too

```
echo '<a href=site.php?id="{$row['id']}">Found {$count} rows in evidence data.</a> <br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes can be escaped using backslash in PHP strings, eg. `"\""` for double quotes and `'\''` for single quotes. But *very often*, the best way to escape complicated HTML (or MySQL for that matter) is to use PHP's HEREDOC syntax:

```
  echo <<<HTML
<a href=site.php?id="$row[id]">Found $count rows in evidence data.</a> <br>

HTML;
```

Note that you **must not** quote the array key (`id`) inside a HEREDOC section. See PHP's [HEREDOC manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for some further details.